# What's a relatively cheap format for selling my nighttime fine art prints that have a lot of black in them?

Tags: printing, selling, framing

Under normal glass they look like a mirror because of how much black is in them. Acrylic is reflective too, and I'd rather have them protected because they're cotton paper, which scratches and scuffs super easily (especially on the black.) Museum glass is expensive, especially at the size I'm going to be printing.

Am I doomed? Should I just try to sell them without frames?

Comment: For clarity: What size range are you aiming for?

Comment: 24x30, 30x40. Somewhere around there.

Comment: Inches or cm? Just for clarification...

Answer (score 4):

I buy museum non glare, UV glass in bulk ( Box of many sheets ) at a glass supplier and cut it my self to fit whatever size i need. Yes it costs more then regular glass but getting it wholesale is MUCH cheaper.

To address the question, there are many alternatives for printing photos. Metal, canvas, Photo transfer, wood etc.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I love plaque mounted images and that's what I get done for all of mine that I sell. They are mounted on wood, heat sealed with a vinyl matte laminate, and the edges are bevelled and painted (any colour possible, I choose black for mine). They look modern, clean, professional and best of all, they have absolutely NO glare or reflections so whatever light you hang them in, you can see the entire image clearly. They are very durable, moisture-resistant, UV-resistant for a century or more. I even have a couple hanging in our steamy bathroom and they remain in perfect condition - one has been there for about 20 years, no warping, no damage of any sort. I hate framing, don't like what glass does to images. Plaque mounting is my solution. It requires specialized equipment so it's not something you can do yourself, but for me, the cost for anything larger than 12x18 works out to equal or less than the cost of matting and framing. I pay the shop an extra couple of dollars to add hanging wire on the back (rather than a slot), so that they can be shown in galleries.

Here is a link to a site with good info about plaque mounting: https://www.canadaoncanvas.com/include/guide_plaque_mounts.php